# How to use React Keycloak?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, keycloak

Did according to [examples](https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak-examples/tree/master/examples), but I get an error:

```
http://localhost:3000/#error=login_required&state=19004288-e312-4782-ac23-9dc038cd7bb0
```

Here is my code:

`keycloak.ts`

```
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';

const keycloak = Keycloak({
url: 'http://192.168.1.179.xip.io:8080/auth',
realm: 'howtowork',
clientId: 'how-to-pay',
});

export default keycloak;
```

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { ReactKeycloakProvider } from '@react-keycloak/web';
import keycloak from './backend/keycloak';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import Loader from './components/authLoad';
import event from './types/eventLog';
import token from './types/tokenLoger';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ReactKeycloakProvider
      authClient={keycloak}
      LoadingComponent={<Loader />}
      onEvent={event}
      onTokens={token}
    >
        <App />
    </ReactKeycloakProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

I don't think it's a server-side error, although anything is possible)
The provider is too convenient a library, otherwise you have to use a clean keycloak-js

help please(
How to solve this problem?

Comment: i have exactly the same problem right now and nowhere I can find any help like there is an agreement to not help about keycloak for react

Answer (score 1):

Add `initOptions` inside `ReactKeycloakProvider`:

```
<ReactKeycloakProvider
    initOptions={{ onLoad: 'login-required' }}
>
```